# Zend XML routing with parameters

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, routes

I have the following code using normal Zend routing and I need to convert it into Zend routing using XML:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'test/v([0-9]+)-([0-9A-Za-z-:?&\'() ]+)\.html',
    array(
        'action' => 'someAction',
        'controller' => 'someController'
    ),
    array(
       1 => video_id
    ),'test/v%d-%s.html');
$router->addRoute('some-Action', $route);
```

How can I pass parameters in XML and what is the basic syntax of this route in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?  You may want to add the second matched part to a variable too, though.

```
<router>
    <routes>
        <some-action>
            <type>Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex</type>
            <route>test/v([0-9]+)-([0-9A-Za-z-:?&amp;\'() ]+)\.html</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>someController</controller>
                <action>someAction</action>
            </defaults>
            <map>
                <video_id>1</video_id>
            </map>
            <reverse>test/v%d-%s.html</reverse>
        </some-action>
    </routes>
</router>
```

To use it, you can add it directly to your router:

```
$front  = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
$router = $front->getRouter();
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.xml');
$router->addConfig($config->routes);
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Since you're new, please remember to 'accept' the answer if it is in fact a suitable answer for your question.